# How to get value of visible row data in specialCell(xlCellTypeVisible)

Tags: excel, vba

I have columns Reference, Count and Code. I am filtering column code one by one and after filtering the data, I wanted to get the value of visible rows only. With this, I used SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).

In the column code, the first selection in the filter is "IG". So this will only leave the first row of my data, and the rest will be hidden below it. Below is my data:

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      Reference      |     Count        |       Code
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          A1         |         4        |        IG
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          A2         |         3        |        IH
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          A2         |         5        |        IH
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          A2         |         6        |        IH
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          A2         |         8        |        IH
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          A2         |         8        |        IH
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          A2         |         8        |        IH
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          A3         |         8        |        II
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          A3         |         10       |        II
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          A3         |         11       |        II
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          A4         |         15       |        VO
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

Here the code i tried:

```
Sub Try()
Dim cl As Range, rng As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastColumn As Long
Dim StartCell As Range
Set StartCell = Range("B2")



LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, StartCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row

 Set rng = Range(StartCell, Cells(LastRow, 2))

For Each cl In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    MsgBox cl

Next cl


End Sub
```

Above code works well with the rest of filtered data such as "IH", "II" and "VO" since the hidden rows are in between. Unlike "IG" the rest of the hidden rows are below of it.

When I try to filter "IG" first, it only shows me the value "reference", "count", "code" and never stops looping.

How would I adjust my code to cater this kind of scenario since most likely, I will encounter the same in the future data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start your range from `B1` and skip the First row will printing.

**Here Try This:**

```
Sub Try()

Dim cl As Range, rng As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastColumn As Long
Dim rw As row

Dim StartCell As Range
Set StartCell = Range("B1")

LastRow = Cells(Rows.count, StartCell.Column).End(xlUp).row

Set rng = Range(StartCell, Cells(LastRow, 2))

For Each cl In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    If Not cl.row = 1 Then MsgBox cl

Next cl


End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Mikku! Never thought with 'if not', it will solve my problem.